# Fastest algorithm to find 2nd biggest element in Max Heap (with duplicates)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

If you have a max heap containing n integers, what would be the most efficient way to find the second largest element? The heap can contain duplicates, so the heap with `n-1` max values and `1` other value would return the other value

For example, a heap containing the numbers:

```
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4
```

would return the value `3`.

Is there a way of doing this in faster than `O(n)` runtime?

Comment: How would you do it without touching every element at least once?

Comment: Technically in a max heap when you pop the root, you are replacing it with the second largest element. So pop the root , re-heapify with the last element in the heap, put the root back and restore the heap. 

Alternatively the second largest will be one of the children of the root, so you could just check one of those

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you can peek without actually popping elements.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-heap-in-java/).  By my reckoning, your worst-case performance ought to be O(log n), and might even be O(1).

Comment: @Srini, the question is to exclude the *same* value (when there are duplicates), and ensure to return the lesser value.

Comment: Worst case will be *O(n)* when all values are equal to the max value, except one. That one value will be in a leaf of the heap and if you're unlucky, it might be the last one that bubbles up.

Comment: @trincot Ahh, I missed that. In that case it is impossible to go faster than O(n). Why? Due to the fact that you don't know where the second largest element will occur in the heap till you get there.

Comment: One way around this, is to implement a variant of the max heap: one that is accompanied by a hashmap. When a value is already in the heap (and map), then its frequency (a value in the map) is incremented, but it is not added again in the heap. That way you have a heap with unique values only, without losing information -- since you have the frequencies in the map. With such a heap you can get the 2nd max value in *O(1)* time by peeking the two children of the root.

Comment: Well.. the more that I think about it I think you can do it in `log(n)`. Why? Because the only impediment to finding the second largest element is a string of repeated max values. But one thing is certain. The second largest element will be the child of one of those max values. You can perform a modified binary search on the heap to find the position where the repeated max values end. Once you do that the second largest element will be within the `k` elements to the right of the last max value. Where `k` is the number of children of every node in your heap

Comment: @Srini, it is not guaranteed that the same values are in a "string". Siblings can be the same value too, after values have been added/deleted/added.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that is for a heap without duplicates, i believe

Comment: @trincot that is a good answer, however I think this is in the case that each value comes with accompanying data (for example, if each value is a key value pair, with each key being the same value)

Comment: @AbhishekPatel, in that case the hashmap could have that data: a map entry would have as key the value to compare, and as value an *array* of data elements that share that compare-value. The heap would only store the compare-values (uniquely). Would this be a solution?

Comment: To all who think there's a simple solution: The specific example contained only two values: one repeated many times, and the other existing only once. But the general question said only that "the heap can contain duplicates". With no restrictions on the number of values or the number of times an individual value  can be repeated, it's easy to create cases where the 2nd largest element occurs at any position in the heap. This cannot be solved faster than O(n) without the use of an auxiliary data structure.

Comment: @trinicot you are right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this with better time complexity than *O(n)*. With the example data you give (`4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4`) the heap could for example be one of these two:

```
             4                      4
           /   \                  /   \
         4       4              4       4
        / \     / \            / \     / \
       4   4   4   4          4   4   3   4
      / \                    / \
     4   3                  4   4
```

... the 3 could be in any leaf node, as this depends on the order of insertion. When you start a traversal from the root, there is no way to know whether the 3 is at the left or the right.

If you are open to use a slightly alternative data structure, then it can be done in *O(1)*:

Store unique values in the heap. Use a hashmap to store information about the value you add. In the simple case this "information" could be an occurrence counter. So the next time you want to insert the *same* value in the structure, you would detect it was already in the hashmap and only increment the corresponding occurrence counter and not touch the heap.

For the above example the data structure would be as follows:

```
    heap              hashmap
                    key | value (=frequency)
       4           -----+-------------------
      /              4  |  8
     3               3  |  1
```

In case your data elements are complex structures combining a key with some related data (properties), then you would still only store the key in the heap without duplicates. The hashmap would then not give a counter for each key, but an array of actual data elements that share that same key.

So to be clear, the implementation of operations like insertion, deletion and look up would have to be customised. Here is some pseudo code assuming the existence of two variables `heap` and `hashmap` which have the corresponding behaviour:

```py
function insert(element):
    key = element.key
    if key not in hashmap:
        hashmap.set(key, new Array)
        heap.insert(key)
    arr = hashmap.get(key) # get a reference to the array
    arr.append(element) # add element to array, affecting the hashmap-stored value

function extract(): # remove max element
    if heap.size() == 0:
        return # No more data
    key = heap.peek() # look at root value
    arr = hashmap.get(key) # get a reference to the array
    element = arr.pop() # extract from array, affecting the hashmap-stored value
    if arr.length() == 0:
        heap.extract()
        hashmap.delete(key)
    return element

function peek(): # return element with max value
    if heap.size() == 0:
        return # No more data
    key = heap.peek() # look at root value
    arr = hashmap.get(key)
    element = arr[-1] # last element in array
    return element
```

You can get the greatest value that is less than the max value as follows:

```
key = max(heap.root.children())
```

... and then depending on what you expect as return value, you could also fetch a corresponding data element from the hashmap, or even all of them (when there are duplicates).

Comment: yes, this is what i was looking for. Of course, based on the comments, it is clear that without an auxillary data structure, we can't solve it in faster than `O(n)` time